# View performance with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are considering moving a lot of our application traffic through 3 or 4 sql views.

Our engineering team is used to working with sprocs and using parameters to filter the results down (for performance, etc).

One concern that has come up: if there are 10,000 rows in a table and the view does not have a built in where clause that's 10,000 rows going through the view (or is it?).

To restate one of my guy's questions:

Assuming vwMonkeys points to tblMonkeys, how does the performance of

```
select * from tblMonkeys m where m.type = 'orangutang'
```

compare with

```
select * from vwMonkeys m where m.type = 'orangutang'
```

?

And does passing all that data through the view tie up a lot of memory before it gets filtered outside the view?

Comment: you can compare the execution plans. If the view is a simple `SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable`, then both queries will most likely have the same plans

Comment: You're thinking about views all wrong. No data "passes through" a view. A view is just a definition of a query. SQL Server will use that definition to decide how to query for data, but it's still getting the data directly from the underlying tables.

Comment: View does not exists, does not work, does not store data, has no performance. It is a written down and named piece of t-sql which will be embedded into your final query.

Comment: To add to what Tom H said, if you use a view in a query, picture it as though the view name were substituted with the query definition of the view.